# How to check if a table row contains a certain button in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, contains, closest

I have an HTML table that is filled dynamically and only shows a certain button in the first column if specific conditions are met, otherwise this button does not appear.

**The button looks as follows** (it always has the name = voidBtn):

```
<input type="button" name="voidBtn" value="Void" />
```

How can I check whether the current row contains this button or not ?

**I was thinking of something like the following but didn't know how to write this the right way:**

```
if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=void]') ...
```

OR

```
if($(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1):contains('voidBtn')") ...
```

I just need to know if the current row has such a button as then I want to click on it and do some other stuff.

Comment: `if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=void]').length > 0) ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is exactly what I need. Would you like to post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of checking should be fine, you just need to ask if it found it with length:

```
if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=void]').length > 0){
    // there is a button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering $(this) as current row then you can find button like this...

```
$(this).find('input[name=voidBtn]')
```

Answer (score 0):

**$( '#'+tableId + "> tbody > tr> td").find('td','searched-string')**

Here is the Example where we can **find an element  inside a row** containing searched-string.Here yoy may use other option as my string was coming for input text field.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to find **all the rows** of the table that contains a particular String **"STRING"** then you may write like this

```
**$('#tableid > tbody').find('tr','STRING')**
```

You may also count the number of row by

```
**$('#tableid > tbody').find('tr','STRING').length**
```

In Above answer i already declared `tableid` as Var in my Jquery Code.